# Change setted model field in admin panel

Tags: django

Here is my model:

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    monthly_limit = models.IntegerField(choices=STEPS_FOR_MONTHLY_USER_LIMIT,
                                        default=STEPS_FOR_MONTHLY_USER_LIMIT[8][1])
```

Choices in my setting are some numbers (10, 20, etc)

Here is my admin registration of this model:

```
from models import Dummy
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Dummy)
```

In admin panel logically when i go to Dummy model in gives to fill up field 1, filed1 and monthly_limit with choice filed (10, 20, etc.).

Is there way to eliminate this choices for monthly_limit filed in admin panel. Because i want the admin to be able to put whatever positive integer he wants, without any restrictions ?

Comment: What are the `choices` for, then? Do you want to validate input everywhere else except the admin panel?